# Neo4j: ERROR [o.n.k.i.DatabaseHealth] Database panic: The database has encountered a critical error, and needs to be restarted

Tags: neo4j

The Neo4J service is failing with following error log, please help.

We are trying to configure Neo4j in one of our Dev Server to do some POCs, but after installation the Neo4j service is failing with following error.

```
2018-03-21 10:34:17.935+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.i.DatabaseHealth] Database panic: The database has encountered a critical error, and needs to be restarted. Please see database logs for more details. Failed to apply transaction: null
org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionApplyKernelException: Failed to apply transaction: null
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.apply(RecordStorageEngine.java:334)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI$RecoveryVisitor.visit(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI$RecoveryVisitor.visit(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:118)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery.init(Recovery.java:128)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:521)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:58)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.BlockingBootstrapper.start(BlockingBootstrapper.java:41)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.start(CommunityEntryPoint.java:42)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to flush label updates
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexBatchTransactionApplier.applyPendingLabelAndIndexUpdates(IndexBatchTransactionApplier.java:116)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexBatchTransactionApplier.close(IndexBatchTransactionApplier.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.BatchTransactionApplierFacade.close(BatchTransactionApplierFacade.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.apply(RecordStorageEngine.java:331)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: org.neo4j.index.internal.gbptree.TreeInconsistencyException: GSPP WRITE failure
  Pointer state A: CRASH
  Pointer state B: CRASH
  Generations: A < B | GB+Tree[file:D:\NEO_HOME\data\databases\graph.db\neostore.labelscanstore.db, layout:LabelScanLayout[version:0.1, identifier:21483684112629824, keySize:10, valueSize:8], generation:7/9]
    at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.checkFailure(WorkSync.java:182)
    at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.access$100(WorkSync.java:49)
    at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync$1.await(WorkSync.java:132)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexBatchTransactionApplier.applyPendingLabelAndIndexUpdates(IndexBatchTransactionApplier.java:112)
    ... 26 more
```

Thanks in advance.